# Entity Framework - The data reader is incompatible with the specified complex type

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on a Winforms application and trying to update my employee details form, which calls a stored procedure to update the employee table.. I am using Entity Framework with a database-first approach..

When I submit the form, the data is updated in the backend table, but my application is throwing the below error.

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'dbModel.stored_procedure_Result'. A member of the type, 'ErrorNumber', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Code:

```
public partial class stored_procedure_Result
{
    public Nullable<int> ErrorNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ErrorSeverity { get; set; }
}

ALTER PROCEDURE sp_UpdateEmp
    @EmpId INT,
    @City VARCHAR(50),
    @Age INT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION EMPUPDATE;
        Update tblEmployee
        set City = @City
        where EmployeeId = @EmpId
        EXEC storedProdAgeCalc @EmpId,@Age
        COMMIT TRANSACTION EMPUPDATE;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION EMPUPDATE;

        SELECT 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
    END CATCH;
 END
```

C# code for calling stored procedure:

```
 EMPDB.sp_UpdateEmp(123, 'TEST', 25);
```

I am wondering why my partial class is having ErrorNumber, ErrorSeverity fields, as per my understanding it should have EmpID, City, Age.

I tried deleting the stored procedure from my edmx and adding back again but no luck..

Any help on this ?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: this is just a sample name i have shared, and thanks for letting me know about it.. i was not aware of it.

Comment: "I am wondering why my partial class is having ErrorNumber, ErrorSeverity fields, as per my understanding it should have EmpID, City, Age."  Because in your Select statement in your stored proc... you're not selecting EmpId

Comment: Also, why does ErrorNumber have parenthesis after it in your sp?

Comment: can you show us the SQL code in the Try?

Comment: I have edited my post sql code as well.

Comment: Error_Number() is a function returns the error number of the error that caused the CATCH block of a TRY...CATCH.... so it has a ()

Comment: *as per my understanding it should have EmpID, City, Age* -- Then what if the catch is hit?

Comment: Well, i think since EF isn't generating a model that includes EmpID, City, and Age, you should probably create a DTO for it manually

Comment: Because EF is generating a model based on your `Select` statement hence `_Result` in the class name